# Analysis of housing price data with strong trend and seasonality

Tags: time-series, arima, data-transformation, exponential-smoothing

I am new to time series. I have monthly Zillow data from Chicago.
[image]

Trying to build three good models here.

Tried to make it stationary, but failed.

If I understand correctly, I need to remove the trend and seasonality here.

Any recommendations about:

- which 3-4 modelling techniques would potentially work well here and why?
- which kind of transformation is appropriate here for these models?

Among my options:

- Regression
- ARMA/ARIMA/sARIMA
- Exponential smoothing
- ARFIMA
- Regression with ARMA errors
- VAR and VARIMA

I also took a look at Prophet, but they do not have good monthly approach and for RNN the dataset is too small.

Appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 2):

I would add another option to your list: a basic structural model (see books by Harvey and Durbin-Koopman on state-space models and Kalman filtiering, if you are unfamiliar with the approach).

That said, I can hardly believe that the median price behaves the way you show, unless for some reason unknown to me houses of very different quality and location are transacted at different times of the year. Otherwise, very easy money could be made by buying in the "cheap" season and re-selling at or near the peak.

Comment: Yes, it is a special case. Chicago is very different in comparison with many other cities. Like LA, Miami, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom seasonality to Prophet to handle this, see [here](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/non-daily_data.html#monthly-data).  I think it would work ok.

As you said you have to remove the trend and seasonality but there are two interesting visual things going on with your data:

1. A changepoint in the trend somewhere around 2012
2. The seasonality looks different as well after that point

This is just visual so you may find more out when looking at other views of the data.

But you could simplify this data quite a bit by just modelling the data starting in 2013ish with a simple trend and second order polynomial trend as well as monthly dummies.

If you want to use all the data then smoothers like holt-winters would probably work fine, Prophet would probably work fine. Basically anything that wouldn't try to fit things globally. Also if you use python you could try some [code](https://github.com/tblume1992/LazyProphet) I wrote which tries to do a lot of stuff similar to Prophet but has some other things going on.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for sharing a library! I have seen the custom approach in Prophet too, but have not tried it yet.